# TSQL Stored Procedure retrieve variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was wondering if it's possible to retrieve the results of a stored procedure using another stored procedure.

I have the following as a test example

The first stored procedure is intended to return two values

```
if(object_id('sp_function01')) is not null
    drop procedure sp_function01
go

create procedure sp_function01
as

    declare @lv_res01 char(20)
    declare @lv_res02 char(20)

    set @lv_res01 = 'fn01 result 01'
    set @lv_res02 = 'fn01 result 02'

    select @lv_res01, @lv_res02

go
```

Then the second is intended to retrieve those values and utilize them

```
if(object_id('sp_function02')) is not null
    drop procedure sp_function02
go

create procedure sp_function02
as

    declare @lv_var01 char(20)
    declare @lv_res01 char(20)
    declare @lv_res02 char(20)

    set @lv_var01 = 'variable 01'

    exec sp_function01

    -- catch variables from this function
    -- into lv_res01 and lv_res02

    select @lv_var01, @lv_res01, @lv_res02

go
```

Yet the values for lv_res01 and lv_res02 are NULL and I'm not sure how to actually catch them

Comment: You can't retrieve the values this way. Create first proc with two out parameters. Declare two variables in second procedure and call first proc passing these two variables as out parameter. You would get the desired output.

Comment: The scope of variable is limited and to capture the values from first proc you should convert proc to function and store those values into second SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

First procedure:

```
create procedure sp_function01
@lv_res01 char(20) OUTPUT,
@lv_res02 char(20) OUTPUT
as

    set @lv_res01 = 'fn01 result 01'
    set @lv_res02 = 'fn01 result 02'

    select @lv_res01, @lv_res02

go
```

Second procedure:

```
create procedure sp_function02
as

    declare @lv_var01 char(20)
    declare @lv_res01 char(20)
    declare @lv_res02 char(20)

    set @lv_var01 = 'variable 01'

    exec sp_function01 @lv_res01 OUTPUT, @lv_res02 OUTPUT

    -- catch variables from this function
    -- into lv_res01 and lv_res02

    select @lv_var01, @lv_res01, @lv_res02

go
```

Calling sp_function01 alone (it's more or less same you just need to declare all output parameters and pass them to proc whether from inside another stored procedure or outside of it):

```
DECLARE @lv_res01 char(20)
DECLARE @lv_res02 char(20)

exec sp_function01 @lv_res01 OUTPUT, @lv_res02 OUTPUT
```

Comment: This answer is perfect, thanks a bunch for your help

Comment: As a side question why does it not work if I call it from outside of a stored procedure as exec sp_function01 lv_res01 OUTPUT, lv_res02 OUTPUT, it says must declare the scalar variable res01

Comment: In order to pass an output parameter to a stored procedure you would need to first declare a variable to hold the value. so before calling sp_function01 you would need to declare two variables. I will update my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of local variables is the module in which they are declared so the variables in function02 are not available in function one.  You need to either use `OUTPUT` parameters or use the `INSERT...EXEC` to insert the result set of function02 into a temp table or table variable.

See [how to share data between stored procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) for a thorough discussion of these and other options.