# SQL Server Cursor not returning multiple rows to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I asked a few days ago about the correct ways to return multiple rows of results from a SQL Server stored procedure and it was recommended that I use the following

```
select @var01, @var02
```

Which seems to work fine until I use it in a loop intending to return multiple rows of data such as my current stored procedure

```
if(object_id('sp_looga')) is not null
    drop procedure sp_looga
go

create procedure sp_looga
as

    declare @idno integer
    declare @desc char(50)

    declare colours_cur cursor for
    select co_idno, co_desc from colours
    where co_status != 'A'
    order by co_idno

    open colours_cur
    fetch next from colours_cur into @idno, @desc

    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin

        select @idno, @desc

    fetch next from colours_cur into @idno, @desc
    end
    close colours_cur deallocate colours_cur

go
```

if I execute this inside SQL Server Admin it seems to work perfectly but when I execute it from excel it only returns one row?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need to use a cursor in this case. When you select like that within a cursor you return a series of individual results rather than a single table. While programmatically you could capture each of those results and merge them together I am not sure that you can do that in Excel, nor that you would want to. I would just return the encapsulated query.

```
if(object_id('sp_looga')) is not null
    drop procedure sp_looga
go

create procedure sp_looga
as

    select co_idno, co_desc from colours
    where co_status != 'A'
    order by co_idno

go
```

As a side note - Unless you need to use a stored procedure, you can just run your query from excel as far as I can see by editing your data connection properties definition to be type SQL and entering command text.

**EDIT:**

I had a look at your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489203/tsql-stored-procedure-retrieve-variables) post. You will need to use Dan Guzman's solution using `INSERT...EXEC` to share the results of this procedure between Excel and another procedure. You were actually on the right track in your original solution but instead of `SELECT`ing variable names you should have done something like `INSERT #TEMP EXEC proc_name`. The only caveat is that you need to `CREATE` your temp table first.